# WMV to mp4 Video convertor

Tags: iphone, video, mp4, wmv

I want to convert Video file from format WMV to mp4

for that please suggest any free video convertor so I can convert my full video without having any effects like watermarks and all.

please help and suuggest

thanks

Comment: not a coding question

Comment: Sure is taking long to migrate this question...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and
>   stream audio and video.

Answer (score 0):

[MEncoder](http://www.google.com/search?q=mencoder) should do fine.